# Sending raw data to Zebra TTP 2030 printer and getting its status

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, kiosk, zebra-printers

I'm woking on a `.net` `c#` web app where I need to print on a zebra printer (`TTP2030`) text and barcodes. Using the `RawPrinterHelper` class [from here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091). I pretty much got the commands to the printer, as a unicode string.

So, to print a barcode I do:

```
string enq = Convert.ToChar(5).ToString();
string esc = Convert.ToChar(27).ToString();
string nul = Convert.ToChar(0).ToString();
string rs = Convert.ToChar(30).ToString();
string lf = Convert.ToChar(10).ToString();
string cr = Convert.ToChar(13).ToString();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(esc + "BS" + nul + nul + Convert.ToChar(72).ToString() + nul + nul);
sb.Append(nul + nul + Convert.ToChar(64).ToString() + nul + Convert.ToChar(2).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(2).ToString());
sb.Append(esc + "BW" + nul + "733104000099" + nul);
sb.Append(lf + rs);

RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName, sb.ToString());
```

The mnemonic for that command is

```
< ESC>BS<0><0>< h 48><0><0>
<00><0>< h 40><0><2><2>
< ESC>BW<00>733104000099<00>
< LF>< RS>
```

What I don't know is if I'm sending correctly things like < h 48>. From the manual, a leading `h` followed by a space indicates a hex value. In this case that value represents the `X` coordinate (the low order byte - I don't know what this is) of the barcode.

If this value is in pixels (or mm), **how do I convert to hex and then to the unicode I'm sending to the printer?**

Also, **how do I convert the decimal values I have to send**?

For example for printing a ruler line I send:

`< ESC>r<0><0><0><0><1><230><0><24><3>`

All are decimal values, meaning position, start, stop etc.

**How do I convert this command so I can send to the printer**?

Another thing I cannot get to work is getting data from the printer. There are several commands available, like getting the paper status, the serial number, firmware etc. To try to achieve this first I added

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int ReadPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, StringBuilder data, int buf, out int pcRead);
```

in the `RawPrinterHelper` class. Then I tried to send the command using `SendFileToPrinter` and a `.prn` file I saved from a small app called `kiosk printer toolbox` I got from the zebra website

(I chose to send a file instead of the `SendStringToPrinter` approach I described above because, well, I don't trust I'm doing the right thing there, and also I tested sending a commands file to the printer with several different commands and it worked).

Then called `ReadPrinter(hPrinter, sb, 6, out dwWritten);` but `sb` is empty. The method returns 0. **Does anyone know how I can read data from the printer**? **Is there a totally different approach I should be considering for printing (text and barcodes) and getting the printer status?**

Comment: As an update on this, I've ditched winspool.drv in favor of reading and writing directly to the usb port, using LibUsbDotNet. With winspool I couldn't get any data from the printer, with ReadPrinter or GetPrinterData (most likely I don't know how to use them, I couldn't find anything useful on the subject). LibUsbDotNet is great library and I could easily send commands to the printer (in the same way as described above) and get data from it. The only problem I'm facing now is converting the decimal and hex values for the printer commands and converting the output into something readable.

Answer (score -3):

There is a specific function in java that does this. I'd go check out QZ-Print. You'll only be able to print to a printer that is running locally on your web apps home machine, no one else will be able too. I'd go check that applet out for what you are wanting to do. IT was specifically written for zebra printers.